# Get Layout name in Controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using MVC 5 and want to override the below View method in my MVC controller

```
protected internal virtual ViewResult View(string viewName, string masterName, object model)
```

I can have a number of different layout views so want to get the current layout name at runtime and pass it to the overriden view method. How do I get the layout name at runtime in the controller?

EDIT
I don't think I need to create a custom view engine for what I need to do. I basically only want to set a ViewBag value across multiple methods and controllers and don't want to repeat myself. I have the viewName and model values at runtime, just don't have the layout name to pass as the masterName parameter

```
protected override ViewResult View(string viewName, string masterName, object model)
{
ViewBag.SomeValue = GetValue();            
return base.View(viewName, masterName, model);
}
```

Comment: I think you are talking about creating a custom ViewEngine. take a look at some examples: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/294297/Creating-your-own-MVC-View-Engine-into-MVC-Applica
http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location

Comment: @MichaelLake I don't think I need to create a custom view, I think it is overkill for what I want, I've edited above to show what it is I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @Gene, if it's not easily possible to do what I'm trying with the View method then I'll look at the FilterAttribute. I just thought getting the layout name for the the view would be more straight forward, I may have been wrong on that though.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to accomplish? This is probably hard because it's not supposed to be done.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to make the decision at runtime - Is there some identifier that 
will tell you which Master to use??? Maybe you can make a Switch?

```
Switch (loggedInUser.SomeSpecialValue)
{
Case: "value1":
return "_Layout1.cshtml";
}
```

How else were you planning to make the decision as to which Layout to show?

Edit: Okay extending the above idea - Maybe something like this can help you:

**RouteConfig**

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{layout}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { layout = "default", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

**HomeController**

```
protected override ViewResult View(string viewName, string masterName, object model)
        {
            var layout = RouteData.Values["layout"].ToString();

            switch (layout)
            {
                case "default":
                    return base.View(viewName, "_layout", model);
                case "test":
                    return base.View(viewName, "_layout2", model);
            }

            return base.View(viewName, masterName, model);
        }
```

**Views**
Create Layout views as required, and add them to the Shared folder and the switch statement.

**Test URL's**

```
http://localhost:64372/ -> Default Layout
http://localhost:64372/default/home/index
http://localhost:64372/test/ -> 2nd Layout
http://localhost:64372/test/home/index
```

Hope this maybe works for you??

Comment: Currently there is no custom property set. I didn't think I would need to set one. I thought there would be some property on the Request or ControllerContext or one of the other properties in the request pipeline in the controller that would have the current Layout name and I'd just pass that down to the overriden View method.

Comment: Im still not 100% sure on how you are trying to solve your issue - You have many Layout files (great) and you want to be able to see which one is in use (good) but how are you choosing which one to use in the first place?

Is this your attempt to choose one?

In which case you first need a way of choosing the layout, and then to store that choice (Maybe a cookie), then you will be able to access that value later on again.

Comment: The layouts are just being set through a _ViewStart file. Since I wanted to call my method from a BaseController there could have been different _ViewStart files across multiple different folders. I wanted to do this without add a cookie to store the currently selected Layout property. I'm going to change my approach and just use an ActionFilter instead, and not worry about the Layout page at all. Thank you for your efforts.