# Detect if layout has been specified in a view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In certain situations I would like to enforce a rule that would stop developers on my team from specifying any @Layout in their razor views.  The layout is going to be a constant in some of our views and so I don't want my team members to have to set it correctly or even be concerned with setting it.

To do this I was going to create an action filter and detect if the ViewResult.MasterName was not null/empty and then throw an exception with an insightful error message.  I have tried ActionExecuting, ActionExecuted, ResultExecuted action filters but in all cases the .MasterName property is always empty even when it is specified in the view.  Is it impossible to detect this in an action filter because its set later in the pipeline?  If not available in a action filter is there other mechanisms that could be hooked into to detect and stop this?

Answer (score 0):

The MasterName property is set in `ViewResult` class so setting this property in the e.g. `ActionFilter` will override whatever is specified via `@Layout` in the Razor view:

```
public class LayoutFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
        if (result != null)
        {
            result.MasterName = "~/Views/Shared/_MyLayout.cshtml";
        }
    }
}
```

I do not think there will be a way of directly preventing `@Layout` being set in the razor view, but even if someone did set `@Layout` in the view, it would still get overridden using the above. You can still selectively apply which Controller/ Actions this applies to via the `[LayoutFilter]` attribute.

Another way would to set the desired layout in the `RouteConfig` and then `override ViewResult` as per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398490/get-layout-name-in-controller-method):

Either way, hope it helps.